# Cannot compile boost::asio::spawn program using a boost::asio::yield_context

Tags: c++, c++17, boost-asio

I want to use `boost::asio` to read in `stdout` and `stderr` from multiple `boost::process`es simultaneously. However, I have compilation issues with `boost::asio` and could reconstruct the following minimal example that does not compile:

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/spawn.hpp>

int main() {
    boost::asio::io_context ios;
    boost::asio::spawn(ios,
            [](boost::asio::yield_context ctx) {
            });
    ios.run();
    return 0;
}
```

GCC `10.2.0` with `C++17` enabled and linking to `boost` version `1.72` results in the following:

```
In file included from /usr/include/boost/coroutine/coroutine.hpp:10,
                 from /usr/include/boost/coroutine/all.hpp:11,
                 from /usr/include/boost/asio/spawn.hpp:19,
                 from [...]/main.cpp:3:
/usr/include/boost/coroutine/asymmetric_coroutine.hpp: In function ‘typename boost::coroutines::pull_coroutine<R>::iterator boost::coroutines::begin(boost::coroutines::pull_coroutine<Arg>&)’
/usr/include/boost/coroutine/asymmetric_coroutine.hpp:2364:17: error: ‘begin’ is not a member of ‘boost’
 2364 | { return boost::begin( c); }
```

Comment: I remember seeing this with particular version of boost. Can you upgrade to an even newer version? Oh wait. Maybe I solved it by including `boost/range.hpp` at the time. I don't have 1.72 handy anymore

Answer (score 0):

Yeah this was an missing indirect include in a particular version of boost. See it [live on wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/lm51rqTNvYw735Hp).

Either

- upgrade to boost 1.73, [live](https://wandbox.org/permlink/lm51rqTNvYw735Hp)
- include the relevant headers, [also live](https://wandbox.org/permlink/G25CCpYQ3IFaKrV9):

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/range/begin.hpp>
#include <boost/range/end.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/spawn.hpp>

int main() {
    boost::asio::io_context ios;
    boost::asio::spawn(ios,
            [](boost::asio::yield_context ctx) {
            });
    ios.run();
    return 0;
}
```